# How to speed up django load time?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, azure

Hello guys please I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this website problem I am building a website where users can download digital assets from using Django, for example download website templates, graphics templates and all that. But now the issue is that when it's already hosted it takes a whole lot of time loading up because I think the files are slowing down the website and I don't really know the perfect way to fix this because I'm still kind of a beginner in Django and any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Django is not made to serve large files. You need to serve large files using storage services like  Amazon S3, Google Storage etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is serving static files, you want to use something like Ene Paul suggested: Amazon S3, Azure, Google, etc.

There are other aspects of Django that can slow down page loads. Some tips that I have learned:

- Heavy DOM manipulation should be done with Javascript in lieu of Django Template Language.
- For complex queries, it is more efficient to execute stored procedures on the DB rather than trying to accomplish via the Django ORM method.